# Arrays of Types in attributes

Tags: c#

I want to pass array of Types to attribute, I tried do it this way

```
class CustomAttribute: Attribute 
{
   Type[] included;
   Type[] excluded;
}

[CustomAttribute{included = new Type[] {typeof(ComponentA)}, 
                 excluded = new Type[] {typeof(ComponentB)} }]//dont work  
class Processor 
{
   // something here
}
```

but VS show cant pass Types in attribute.

Do somebody know how to resolve this issue or eventual workaround ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this has nothing to do with arrays, but everything to do with your general syntax. You're using `{ }` for attribute arguments instead of `( )`, and your attribute doesn't have public properties, which are required for named arguments in attributes. Additionally, your attribute class doesn't use `[AttributeUsage(...)]`.

Here's a complete example which *does* compile:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
class CustomAttribute : Attribute 
{
    public Type[] Included { get; set; }
    public Type[] Excluded { get; set; }
}

[CustomAttribute(Included = new Type[] { typeof(string) },
                 Excluded = new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(bool) })]
class Processor 
{
}
```

To make things briefer:

- You can provide a constructor with parameters
- You can use `new[]` instead of `new Type[]`

So:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
class CustomAttribute : Attribute 
{
    public Type[] Included { get; set; }
    public Type[] Excluded { get; set; }

    // Keep a parameterless constructor to allow for
    // named attribute arguments
    public CustomAttribute()
    {
    }

    public CustomAttribute(Type[] included, Type[] excluded)
    {
        Included = included;
        Excluded = excluded;
    }
}

[CustomAttribute(new[] { typeof(string) }, new[] { typeof(int), typeof(bool) })]
class Processor 
{
    // Provide the named version still works
    [CustomAttribute(Included = new[] { typeof(string) },
                     Excluded = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(bool) })]
    public void Method()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some access modifiers missing and you're not using the attribute correctly.

1. You need to make the `included` and `exluded` properties in the `CustomAttribute``` class public:

   ```
   class CustomAttribute: Attribute 
   {
      public Type[] Included { get; set; }
      public Type[] Excluded { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. When you specify values for the members of the Attribute you need to use `()` and not `{}`

   your line is:

   ```
   [CustomAttribute{included = new Type[] {typeof(ComponentA)},excluded = new Type[] {typeof(ComponentB)} }]
   ```

   and it should be:

   ```
   [CustomAttribute(Included = new Type[] {typeof(ComponentA)}, Excluded = new Type[] {typeof(ComponentB)} )]
   ```

   note the `(` after `CustomAttribute` and the `)` before the last `]`.

Comment: Note that you still don't have properties in that code - you have fields. I'd advise using properties instead.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet! Silly oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Type` fields are private. Consider using public properties instead of making fields public. ["Why it is preferable to use public properties instead of public fields"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields/)

Your code won't compile since your syntax for passing parameters to an attribute is incorrect. You need:

```
class CustomAttribute: Attribute 
{
    public Type[] Included { get; set; }
    public Type[] Excluded { get; set; }
}

[CustomAttribute(Included = new Type[] {typeof(ComponentA)}, Excluded = new 
Type[] {typeof(ComponentB)} )]  
class Processor 
{
   // something here
}
```

Notice the parentheses when passing parameters (and not `{}`) to the `attribute` constructor.